# Export All Users Disclaimer From Exchange 2010 With Exchange Management Shell

Tags: powershell, export, exchange-server, exchange-management-shell

I need to Export User Disclaimer From Exchange 2010 With Exchange Management Shell. Is that possible? Example of Disclaimer:

```
Kathleen Mayer
Sales Department
Contoso
www.contoso.com
kathleen@contoso.com
cell: 111-222-1234
```

I tried this script but its result didnt contain disclaimer :

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

try {
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Unable to load Active Directory module, is RSAT installed?"
    Exit
}

$Results = foreach ($User in (Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Department, Mail)) {

    $Mailbox = Get-Mailbox $User.Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($Mailbox) {
        $Mail = $Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        if ($Mail.TotalItemSize.Value -eq $null) {
            $TotalSize = 0
        } else {
            $TotalSize = $Mail.TotalItemSize.Value.ToBytes()
        }

        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Name = $User.Name
            SamAccountName = $User.SamAccountName
            Email = $User.Mail
            Department = $User.Department
            MailboxSize = $TotalSize
            IssueWarningQuota = $Mailbox.IssueWarningQuota
            ProhibitSendQuota = $Mailbox.ProhibitSendQuota
            ProhibitSendReceiveQuota = $Mailbox.ProhibitSendReceiveQuota
        }
    }
}

$Results |
    Select Name, SamAccountName, Email, `
    Department, MailboxSize, IssueWarningQuota, `
    ProhibitSendQuota, ProhibitSendReceiveQuota |
    Export-Csv c:\MailboxSizeByDepartment.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Please see this link : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600437%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

Comment: Hi, can you please input some code you have tried already ?

Comment: tnx sodawillow , I Update My question

Comment: Are you sure not to deal with *signatures* instead of *disclaimers* ? This does definitely look like a signature to me.

Comment: thanks a lot.  you're right . now how can i export all users mail signatures?

Comment: Hehe - I'm doing support for a job, I saw this coming ^^ I don't know about all the available options, but I have always seen signatures stored locally in Exchanges environments. That means you would have to gather it from the computers instead of the server ... Are you able to set a user's signature from the Exchange server ? It seems doable but for OWA : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638117%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx